# cannot find variable in Scanner.in

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I want to create two string arrays with words i give through a scanner, but the compiler keeps telling me "cannot find symbol variable in" in Scanner.in. How do i solve it?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class FollowerInsight {  

        public static void main (String[] args) {
            Scanner fr = new Scanner(Scanner.in);
            Scanner fg = new Scanner(Scanner.in);

            String followers[] = new String[fr];
            String following[] = new String[fg];
    }
}
```

Now its giving me "incompatible types: java.util.Scanner cannot be converted to int" on fr and fg. What should i do?

```
    String followers[] = new String[fr];
    String following[] = new String[fg];
```

What im trying to do is to connect what I wrote on the scanner to fill the string list.
Im sorry im new on programming

Comment: You probably meant `System.in`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner` has no input stream called `in`. I believe what you wanted was [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) which is the standard input stream which reads from the console:

> The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by the host environment or user.

```
Scanner fr = new Scanner(System.in);
```

---

Also it is best to only have one `Scanner` object reading from `System.in`. Next, what is

```
 String followers[] = new String[fr];
```

Supposed to do? I think you're trying to read input from the console (You probably want to use the `nextLine()` and `next()` methods) to read input and put them in your `String[]`

Please read the docs for the [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Comment: Im trying to fill the array followers with what i wrote on the scanner

Comment: @Perico Then use the `next()` and `nextLine()` methods to read the inputs into the `String[]`